# preserving and retrieving user socket from within a servlet

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, authentication, glassfish

i am building an restful ws which i would like to add a instant messaging capabilities ,i understand there is out of the box solutions and restful is not the proper design for such cases,my quastion is the following :

1. if a server such as tomcat or glassfish is running the container ,is there a way to retrieve the socket from within the servlet when a user makes a login request
2. how can i change the server(glassfish or tomcat) policy to keep the socket alive
3. is there a built in mechnishem for user logins from the server itself(assuming i write the database login query) which enables me to trigger a message event to be send for some user\username without caring about how the sockets are managed
4. my motivation is to enable users to send private messages between users \therfore publish subscribe design is not needed
5. what would be the desired design for enableing web services with im
6. can jdbc realm or jmx help here?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to retrieve the socket in a servlet container. And HTTP is by design a stateless request-response protocol. I guess you could not use a different port for this, right?

Comment: i could,but i was tring to avoid migrating the message passing and login outside the servlets ,i am guessing that goes against rest anyway,would you recommend any other protocol or built in server feature to help this cause without binding to an acceptor port socket and managing my sockets,does jboss have sth similar,i am looking for a server which can run ws and have basic xmpp style capabilities,assuming i write my login queries

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is a good idea. I would rather look at the asynchronous capabilities added to the Servlet 3.0 specification (by the way, chat is a typical example for these features). You could also have a look at this solution (specific to RESTful design): http://blog.wordnik.com/introducing-swaggersocket-a-rest-over-websocket-protocol